# FATA[0000] invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, argocd, argoproj, kubeconfig

I'm running my minikube cluster in thw windows laptop computer and trying to setup argo workflows and argo-cli, I already installed the argo-workflow but when I try executing argo commands, it gives me an error :

FATA[0000] invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided

But I see --kubeconfig flag can be used to configure this this setting in argo, I tried the following command to execute with --kubeconfig

```
argo version --kubeconfig "/mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/config"
```

Still I'm getting following error

```
FATA[0000] invalid configuration: [unable to read client-cert /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/C:\Users\madur\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt for minikube due to open /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/C:\Users\madur\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt: no such file or directory, unable to read client-key /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/C:\Users\madur\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.key for minikube due to open /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/C:\Users\madur\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.key: no such file or directory, unable to read certificate-authority /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/C:\Users\madur\.minikube\ca.crt for minikube due to open /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/C:\Users\madur\.minikube\ca.crt: no such file or directory]
```

My kubeconfig file is loacted at /mnt/c/Users/madur/.kube/config becauseI'm using WSL in windows.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using WSL, you should use the Linux filesystem for files.